# Dynamically change line-numbering settings in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings, key-bindings, line-numbers

I know I can change the line-numbering in Visual Studio Code to relative by adding the line `"editor.lineNumbers": "relative",` to the settings.json file, but I am looking for a way to bind it to a keybinding such that I can toggle between absolute (`on`) and relative (`relative`). I've messed with keybindings, but I can't find a command that can temporarily change settings.

I'd prefer to be able to have one key that toggles it between the two, but if there had to be a key to turn it to absolute and another to turn it to relative that would be fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using the extension [Settings Cycler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hoovercj.vscode-settings-cycler), you can toggle between `on` and `relative` using a keyboard shortcut by inserting the following entry in your `keybindings.json` file:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+l",
    "command": "settings.cycle",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
        "id": "relativeLineNumbers",
        "values": [
            {
                "editor.lineNumbers": "on"
            },
            {
                "editor.lineNumbers": "relative"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```